# Cannot write/read string separated by coma into a file

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm trying to write a set of parameters of a structure into a file, and then read it in the program. The structure has a `int` type variable and a `string` type variable(this string is separated by space). I've successfully written and then read the integer part of the structure, but when i try to do the same for the string, the program crashes. I think it has something to do with my the `fprintf` statement, and trying to read a string separated by space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
// creating a FILE variable
FILE *fptr;

// integer variable
int i = 0;
char n[50];

// character variable
struct cliente {
char  nome[50];
int   nif;
};
struct cliente client[0];


// open the file in write mode
fptr = fopen("student", "w");

if (fptr != NULL) {
  printf("File created successfully!\n");
}
else {
  printf("Failed to create the file.\n");
  // exit status for OS that an error occured
  return -1;
}

// get student detail
printf("Enter student name: ");
scanf(" %[^\t\n]c", client[1].nome);
printf("Enter student ID: ");
scanf("%d", &client[1].nif);
// write data in file
fprintf(fptr, "%d %s", client[1].nif, &client[1].nome);

// close connection
fclose(fptr);

// open file for reading
fptr = fopen("student", "r");

// display detail
printf("\Ficheiro:\n");
fscanf(fptr, "%d %s", &i, n);
printf("ID: %d\n", i);
printf(" %s", n);

// close connection
fclose(fptr);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `struct cliente client[0];` Zero length arrays are not legal in C. `client[1]` This references an object that doesn't exist, and it's all [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) after that.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Failed to create the file.\n");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   Strongly suggest: `perror( "fopen to write student failed" );`  This will output to `stderr`, both the error message and the text reason the system, thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `scanf(" %[^\t\n]c", client[1].nome);`  do you think the next character in the input, after the `white space` will be the letter 'c'`?

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(fptr, "%d %s", client[1].nif, &client[1].nome);`   this will output the student ID, a space, then ????.  Suggest removing the '&' before `client[1].nome` so the student name will be output.   why output some variable length for each student?  Suggest:  `fprintf(fptr, "%s", client[1] );` which will output one instance of the struct, the instance that contains the student data.

Comment: given my prior comment,, this: `fscanf(fptr, "%d %s", &i, n);
printf("ID: %d\n", i);
printf(" %s", n);` becomes: `fread( &client[1], sizeof( client[1] ), 1 );`  followed by: `printf("ID: %d\n", client[1].nif.);
printf(" %s", client[1].nome);`  Of course, when calling `fread()` be sure to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring an array of zero length (`struct cliente client[0]`) but referencing the second element in the array (`client[1]`). That could cause a crash.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'm a bit old-school so I just recently discovered this format specifier. I've updated my answer. I'm still not sure how the `c` fits in, but I'll research it.

Comment: Thank you ! That was exactly the problem. just declared the array properly and the code run as expected. The problem was that I'm trying to implement this functionality in other code, and extracted this part to try to work at a smaller chunk. The thing is that in the other code the array it's declared later on by user input. Problem Solved!